# In-memory VS plocal comparison

Tags: orientdb

I am about to start working on a bit of graph logic that it is not meant to store anything but to pass results to the threads that hold storage.

does the in-memory instance have the same memory cost as the other (local, etc)?

or is it cheaper since none of the hard i/o occurs?

Are transactions necessary for memory only instances? It seems the worst it can happen is an O-Of-M exception when populating the graph.

Shouldn't it be faster because there is no disk access?

thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Basically the difference between them is that in memory storage all data remains in memory, while plocal storage consists of several components each of those components use disk data through disk cache.

For more inforamtion take a look at this: http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Paginated-Local-Storage.html

**UPDATE**

I don't know if it helps but here you can find some tutorials/lessons about OrientDB: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Quick-Start.html#more-on-tutorials

Comment: I use plocal with great results. The question is more about in memory. I will continue and if I hit a roadblock will return with questions. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if it helps but here you can find some tutorials/lessons about OrientDB: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Quick-Start.html#more-on-tutorials
I have updated my answer with the link.